# std::string implicit conversion priority, string_view over const char*

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I have two overloaded functions:

```
void Set(const char * str) { std::cout << "const char * setter: " << str << "\n"; }
void Set(const std::string_view & sv) { std::cout << "string_view setter: " << sv << "\n"; }
```

And I call Set() on a `std::string`. It picks the `std::string_view` overload rather than the const char * overload, i.e. it chooses the implicit conversion of `std::string` to `std::string_view` over `std::string` to `const char *`.

Is this a guaranteed behaviour in `std::string`, or was their choice arbitrary? If it is a guaranteed behaviour, how did they make it prefer the string_view conversion over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string` has a non-explicit [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view) to `std::string_view`, so it could convert to `std::string_view` implicitly. But `std::string` doesn't have a conversion operator to `const char*`, it can't convert to `const char*`. You have to call its [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method explicitly to get a `const char*`:

```
Set(some_string.c_str());
```

Comment: Doh, that explains everything. Thanks! I should've checked in std::string.